# Apenas com CSS existe alguma forma de fazer um "Toast"? Um elemento que sobe e depois clique para fecha-lo?

Tags: html5, css3, ux, ui, toasts

No mobile existe um componente bem comum que é conhecido como "**Toast**", porém fiquei pensando em como adapta-lo apenas com HTML e CSS

[image: toa]

Existe alguma forma de fazer algo como esse "componente" acima apenas utilizando CSS e HTML, sem *framework* ou outras bibliotecas?

Eu cheguei nesse modelo abaixo, mas gostaria de deixa-lo funcional como esses `alerts` do tipo "**Toast**" que vemos principalmente no Android...

**Como fazer ele subir e ficar parado, e depois clicar no X para fecha-lo?**

```css
.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: .5em;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
}
.toast {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.toast p,
.toast a {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<br>
<label class="btn" for="open">TOAST</label>
<br>
<div class="toast">
    <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor.
    </p>
    <a href="#">
        X
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Então, nessa caso é necessário utilizar javascript para manipular esses eventos e realizar a alteração no CSS, irei fazer um exemplo

Comment: @TácioBrito sei que com JS ou jQuery é possível, mas a minha intenção justamente é fazer apenas com HTML e CSS

Comment: Entendi, o efeito de subir e descer é possível fazer, mas o evento de clicar só é possível com javascript

Comment: Hugo minha pergunta não tem nada a ver com a sua :) Cara como que eu faço para fazer estas animações?

Comment: @LeAndrade esse exemplo em particular do componente eu peguei do Quasar vc pode ver aqui, basta clicar em qq botão: http://v0-13.quasar-framework.org/components/toast.html agora para gravar a tela que foi o que eu fiz foi usando um programinha simples chamado ScreenToGif. Eu simplesmente coloquei para gravar esse pedacinho da tela e ele salva como um gif animado https://www.screentogif.com/?l=pt_br

Comment: Jóia man, era um programinha assim mesmo que precisava. Obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @LeAndrade esse programinha é bem leve! Menos de 3mb :D tem me ajudado bastante e funciona super bem. Só sinto falta de poder desenhar na tela, mas tb ainda não procurei isso a fundo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você consegue fazer algo muito próximo utilizando um elemento que pode receber o foco do usuário em conjunto com o seletor `:focus-within` do CSS. Com esse seletor, você poderá alterar a posição da mensagem do *toast* quando seu botão possuir o foco.

```css
.toast > .btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: .5em;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
}
.toast > .btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
}

.toast > .toast-message {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    bottom: -83px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: bottom .5s ease-out;
}
.toast > .toast-message {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toast:focus-within > .toast-message {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="toast">
  <button class="btn" for="open">TOAST</button>
  <p class="toast-message">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
</div>
```

Perceba que ao invés de separar os elementos de ação (botão) e a mensagem, ambos estão dentro de um mesmo elemento pai (`div.toast`). Assim, quando o elemento `.toast` possui algum filho com o foco do usuário - nesse caso o botão -, a mensagem `.toast > .toast-message` será exibida alterando a posição em relação à borda inferior da tela.

O requisito que não é satisfeito com essa solução é fechar a mensagem apenas pressionando o X na mensagem, mas em compensação, qualquer clique fora do botão irá ocultar a mensagem, visto que este perderá o foco.

> O mesmo efeito você consegue com `.btn:focus + .toast-message { bottom: 0; }`, que substitui o uso de `:focus-within`, como pode ser visto em https://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/rz9pswax/.

Comment: Muito bom! Já é uma opção, mesmo com o detalhe do foco

Answer (score 2):

Para quem quiser um versão que só se fecha ao clicar em um botão uma opção é usando `:target`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim da para fazer um *link* com um `href` chamando o `ID` do **Toast**, e dentro do **Toast** tem um outro *link* com um `href` vazio, a intenção desse `href` vazio é fazer com que o **Toast** perda o `:target`, assim ele se fecha voltando para posição original.

**OBS:** Tenha em mente que o **Toast** fecha quando o `:target` é feito em outro elemento. Então mesmo tendo um botão para fechar, vc pode fecha-lo *(querendo ou não)* clicando em algum outro link, pois quando o **Toast** perde o `target` na `url` ele vai se fechar...

Veja o código referente a imagem acima:

```css
.btn {
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: .5em;
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    padding: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 250ms;
}
.btn:hover {
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
}
.toast {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    bottom: -100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: rgb(100, 0, 100);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    transition: bottom 500ms;
}
.toast:target {
    bottom: 0;
}
.toast p,
.toast a {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<br>
<a class="btn" href="#toast">TOAST</a>
<br>
<div class="toast" id="toast">
    <p>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor.
    </p>
    <a href="#">
        X
    </a>
</div>
```